# use if and for in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm going to use if in blade `Laravel` that when they select `married` show more input.

And also take `int` for children for example when type 4 show more 4 input.

It is a form that client put their information and if they have wife another input shows to get their name and if they have children show more input.

I couldn't write the codes please help me

```html
<div class=" form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="" class="text-form"> وضعیت تاهل  </label>
    <select class="form-select" name="material" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option value="single">single</option>
        <option value="married">married</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="text-form">  number of children  </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="childeren  ">
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use if and for in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052837/use-if-and-for-in-laravel)

Comment: use JQuery or laravel livewire  https://laravel-livewire.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check “If statements” at [laravel.com docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements)

**Example**

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `javascript (jQuery)` for this job:

Something like the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hidden_input").hide();
  $("select.legal_state").change(function(){
    if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() == 'married') {
      $("#hidden_input").show();
    } else {
       $("#hidden_input").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class=" form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="" class="text-form"> وضعیت تاهل  </label>
    <select class="form-select legal_state" name="material">
        <option value="single">single</option>
        <option value="married">married</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="hidden_input"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="text-form">  number of children  </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="childeren  ">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: I made it disappear again when you select `single`